# Pass function to map

Tags: javascript

**Why** aren't the two following statements equivalent:

```js
const output1 = [..."123"].map(parseInt);
const output2 = [..."123"].map(e => parseInt(e));

console.log(output1);
console.log(output2);
```

What concept am I missing?

Comment: It would have been helpful to include the outputs - once you have NaN, parseInt and map together the answer's easy to find. Another common reason `.map(thing)` doesn't work, although it doesn't apply to this specific case, is https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` will pass the index it is currently looking at as the second argument to the callback function.

`parseInt` takes an optional second argument which sets the radix (number base) it is parsing from.